# Refresh ListView from within a custom ListView class

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-arrayadapter, android-loadermanager

I use a `LoaderManager` to fill the Adapter of my `ListView` with data. I implemented the `LoaderManager.Callbacks` but I can't refresh the `ListView` to display the new data.
Calling `adapter.notifyDatasetChanged()`, `invalidate()` or `postInvalidate()` does nothing.

Some code:

```
@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<ArrayList<Items>> arrayListLoader, ArrayList<Items> entries) {
    Log.i("TAG", "+++ onLoadFinished() called! +++");
    switch (arrayListLoader.getId()) {
        case LOADER_ID:
            mAdapter.setData(entries);
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            invalidate();
            break;
    }
}
```

The `adapter` is initialized in the default constructor of the `ListView` class.

Adapter and ListView initialization (stripped down to relevant parts):

```
public CustomListView(Activity activity) {
    [...]
    mAdapter = new CustomEntryAdapter(mActivity, R.layout.row_monthlistview);
    setAdapter(mAdapter);
    mCallbacks = this;
    LoaderManager loaderManager = mActivity.getSupportLoaderManager();
    loaderManager.initLoader(LOADER_ID, null, mCallbacks);
    [...]
}
```

The `setData` method of my custom `Adapter`:

```
public void setData(ArrayList<Items> data) {
    clear();
    if (data != null) {
        for (Items aData : data) {
            add(aData);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: May you can reinitialize the adapter, try to reinitialize it....

Comment: do you  overide your getCount() method inside your adapter?

it should be like return entries.size();

Comment: @Pragnani Thanks, I already tried to create a new `Adapter` and set it to the `ListView`. Doesn't worked.

Comment: @Vetal.lebed Thanks, it isn't overriden. I will try to return `entries.size()` and will report back.

Comment: @Vetal.lebed I overwrote the `getCount()` method and returned a hardcoded value (in my example 3), which just produce 3 empty rows.

Comment: can you show the full code of adapter?

Comment: @Vetal.lebed In the Adapter is only getView overriden, to format the ListView accordingly, and the second method, setData, is already in my question.

Comment: from your code i can imagine that you maybe use a one layout for all rows. It is impossible. And you have to override a getCount() that will return a enty.size(). It tells to adapter count of rows.

Comment: The Adapter is working, if I set it to the ListView without the loader (on the Ui Thread, which is bad). The issue is, that the data isn't correctly set to the ListView. The loader is working, too. I checked it. The data is returned in the onLoadFinished method and can be accessed.

Comment: Do you trying refresh list from another Thread ? if yes. You should use UI thread (Activity.runOnUiThread(Runnable)). Because android required it. Or you can use AsyncTask and refresh list in onPost() method.

Comment: The List is refreshed from onLoadFinished, as written above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be impossible in my specific case. The `LoaderManager` is the root of the issue, I can't bind n `LoaderManager` to n `views`.

lim n -> ∞

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
yourGlobalList.clear();
yourGlobalList.addAll(entries)
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: This is nearly the same what the `setData` method of my adapter does.

Answer (score -3):

I think you need to call listView.setAdapter() method after calling notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: The Adapter is already initialized and set to the `ListView`. Nevertheless, I did it before and it doesn't helped.